# SQL - Tags searching query

Tags: sql, sqlite, search, tags

I have following table in my database:

```
ID  name
1   x
2   x
3   y
1   y
1   z
```

Now I want to select only this objects (ID's) which has both 'x' and 'y' value s tag name. In this case this will be only record with ID = 1 because sought values set ('x' and 'y') is subset of this record possible names set ('x', 'y' and 'z').

How to write a SQL query?

**Thanks for help :)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select id
from t
where name in ('x', 'y')
group by id
having count(*) = 2;
```

If you care about performance you might want to compare this to:

```
select id
from t tx join
     t ty
     on tx.id = ty.id and tx.name = 'x' and ty.name = 'y';
```

The first version is easier to generalize to more tags.  Under some circumstances, the second might have better performance.

Comment: Likely, in the case of the first query, this shouldn't be a problem unless `Name` is not unique in relation to `ID`, but it could be selected if the `ID` contains multiple of the same `name` value. The second query would probably be more ideal.

Comment: @gmiley . . . If duplicates are an issue, then just use `count(distinct name) = 2`.   The sample data doesn't suggest duplicates are an issue.  Similarly, if `name` could be `NULL`, then the OP would need to explain how to handle those values.

Comment: Ya, it isn't a huge deal, but thought it was at least worth pointing out in the slight chance it could come up for the OP. =)