# SQL For each Account ID, show services with only these tags, exclude those without

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm pretty new to SQL and I have a report I'm trying to generate from our billing database. Our structure is that each account can have many services and all accounts have certain services (named Owner) and older accounts have certain services (named Convert - from an old billing system migration). Some accounts also have an Interest Tag (from those who haven't paid).

I am looking for a list of accounts that have only have the drainage tag on them, but can have the mandatory/optional service type tags.

the code I have so far is

```
Select      
            sa.ACCT_ID,
            sa.SERVICE_ID,
            sa.SERVICE_TYPE

from    SERVICES sa

Where   sa.SERVICE_TYPE in ('DRAINAGE','OWNER','CONVERT','INTEREST')
;
```

This currently shows all accounts with services tagged drainage, owner, convert, or interest but I want ones that show only have Drainage AND Owner, but can include convert or interest.

We have 58 other service types and I can't figure out how to exclude accounts where they are present.

Any help would be greatly appriciated

Comment: Can you add sample input and output to better understand?

Comment: Seems like 'convert' and 'interest' are irrelevant here. What is the unique key in this table? Is it `ACCT_ID,Service_Type`? or is service_type stuffed into a single field? This is pretty key to answering the question. Sample data will help illuminate this

Comment: Here's one solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226795/sql-tags-searching-query Here's another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378087/sql-tag-list-and-tag-filtering It really depends on your schema.

Comment: to answer @Nick.McDermaid, the unique key to this table is `SERVICE_ID`. Some sample data would include

`Acct ID, Service ID, Service Type

001, 123, owner
001, 124, drainage
001, 125, drillings
002, 126, owner
002, 127, convert
002, 128, usage
003, 129, owner
003, 130, environment
004, 131, owner
004, 132, drainage
004, 133, usage
005, 134, owner
005, 135, drainage
005, 136, convert
005, 137, interest`

I would ideally just include the `ACCT_ID` for each on that includes drainage (and the other allowed ones) but excludes anything with other service types like 'drillings'

Answer (score 0):

OK so you have a tag per row (good) rather than a bunch of tags squeezed into a field in a single row. The usual approach is to only include accounts with the tag but also *count* the number of tags and make sure it is two. Like this:

So.. this will return all acounts (a unique list) that have either one tag or both:

```
Select      
            sa.ACCT_ID,
            count(*)
from    SERVICES sa
Where   sa.SERVICE_TYPE in ('DRAINAGE','OWNER')
group by sa.ACCT_ID
```

.. but this one will only include records that have both:

```
Select      
            sa.ACCT_ID,
            count(*)
from    SERVICES sa
Where   sa.SERVICE_TYPE in ('DRAINAGE','OWNER')
group by sa.ACCT_ID
having count(*) = 2
```

Logically speaking, the requirement *but can include convert or interest* doesn't matter here - the returned records may or may not include these but it's not tested for.

This is one way to do it. The links in my comments show a bunch of other ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the result that I'm looking for:
I made a list of account id's for all services without the tags by:

```
select  DISTINCT ACCT_ID

From    SERVICES

Where SERVICE_TYPE not in ('DRAINAGE','OWNER','INTEREST','CONVERT','DRN-NRSC','DRN-RSC ','DRN-DWL')
```

then I excluded these account ID's from another search and filtered for only Drainage. I think I've got everything. My final code was (something like this)

```
SELECT  Acct_ID,
        SERVICES_ID,
        SERVICE_TYPE as SA_TYPE,

FROM    SERVICES sa

Where   ACCT_ID not in 
    (
    select  DISTINCT ACCT_ID

    From    SERVICES

    Where SERVICE_TYPE not in ('DRAINAGE','OWNER','INTEREST','CONVERT','DRN-NRSC','DRN-RSC ','DRN-DWL')
    )

and     SERVICE_TYPE in ('DRAINAGE','DRN-NRSC','DRN-DWL','DRN-RSC ')

Order by acct_id
```

Comment: Was my answer of any use?